# filtering on two variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that has 57 locations "homes" for each of those locations I have 10 other locations "weather stations" that are ranked by nearness in miles. Then I have a column that has the quadrant the weather station falls in around the homes so 1-4. 
I am trying to write code in R that takes the closest weather station and it's quadrant, then take the next closest in a different quadrant and the third in a different quadrant. So that I have a triangle based on the closest stations.

```
    loc           station                   nearness  quadrant 
1   Abilene-KS   SALINA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT       1         2
2   Abilene-KS   MARSHALL ARMY AIRFIELD         2         1
3   Abilene-KS   MULTI PURPOSE RANGE            3         1
4   Abilene-KS   MANHATTAN REGIONAL AIRPORT     4         3
5   Abilene-KS   MANHATTAN 6 SSW                5         1 
6   Abilene-KS   BLOSSER MUNICIPAL AIRPORT      6         4
7   Abilene-KS   NEWTON-CITY-COUNTY AIRPORT     7         1
8   Abilene-KS   EMPORIA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT      8         2 
9   Abilene-KS   HUTCHINSON MUNICIPAL ARPT      9         4
10  Abilene-KS   COLONEL JAMES JABARA ARPT      10        3
11  Archbold-OH  SALINA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT       1         2 
12  Archbold-OH  MARSHALL ARMY AIRFIELD         2         1
13  Archbold-OH  MULTI PURPOSE RANGE            3         3
14  Archbold-OH  MANHATTAN REGIONAL AIRPORT     4         1
15  Archbold-OH  MANHATTAN 6 SSW                5         4   
16  Archbold-OH  BLOSSER MUNICIPAL AIRPORT      6         4
17  Archbold-OH  NEWTON-CITY-COUNTY AIRPORT     7         2
18  Archbold-OH  EMPORIA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT      8         1
19  Archbold-OH  HUTCHINSON MUNICIPAL ARPT      9         3
20  Archbold-OH  COLONEL JAMES JABARA ARPT      10        2
```

I wish I could say that I have some code to show what I have tried but everything has gotten me nowhere so I'm lost. Any ideas?

for these two locations, I would like a new data frame with

```
    loc           station                   nearness  quadrant 
1   Abilene-KS   SALINA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT       1         2
2   Abilene-KS   MARSHALL ARMY AIRFIELD         2         1
3   Abilene-KS   MANHATTAN REGIONAL AIRPORT     4         3
4   Archbold-OH  SALINA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT       1         2 
5   Archbold-OH  MARSHALL ARMY AIRFIELD         2         1
6   Archbold-OH  MULTI PURPOSE RANGE            3         3
```

Comment: So for the first loc you would keep rows 1,2 and 4, and for the second loc rows 11,12 and 13, is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: can you paste the expected results that you need to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
distinct(loc,quadrant,.keep_all=T) %>%
group_by(loc) %>%
top_n(-3,nearness)
```

This returns:

```
          loc                    station nearness quadrant
        <chr>                      <chr>    <int>    <int>
1  Abilene-KS   SALINA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT        1        2
2  Abilene-KS     MARSHALL ARMY AIRFIELD        2        1
3  Abilene-KS MANHATTAN REGIONAL AIRPORT        4        3
4 Archbold-OH   SALINA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT        1        2
5 Archbold-OH     MARSHALL ARMY AIRFIELD        2        1
6 Archbold-OH        MULTI PURPOSE RANGE        3        3
```

Comment: @Frank I thought distinct only kept the specified variables, but I've just seen that you could specify .keep_all=T, so I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok that makes sense I did not know about top_n. Thanks for the help!